# Not able to find JmDNS service in other machines

Tags: bonjour, zeroconf, jmdns

Using jmdns 3.4.1, I'm able to see the services advertised by the machines in the LAN, I can also create a service and register it, so that I can see it in my machine. However, when I create a new service in another machine of the LAN, I cannot see it in my machine.
I'm using the following code in the other machine:

```
service = ServiceInfo.create("_workstation._tcp.local.", "service1" ,80, "foobar"); 
jmdns = JmDNS.create();
jmdns.registerService(service);
```

Answer (score 4):

That should be the problem of address.
When you create an object `jmdns`, it's better to add the `inetaddress`.

**Example:**

```
InetAddress Address = InetAddress.getLocalHost(); 
final JmDNS  jmdns = JmDNS.create(Address);
```

Comment: yes you are totally right.. I've already olved this problem by adding the ip address.. thanks a lot anyway

Comment: Thank you...worked for me too...but WHY does this work better (InetAddress)?